Confidence level and error margin calculation via python
I wanted to calculate confidence level and error margin via python language using numpy. However, I am not sure whether formaulation is true or not. I could not apply the formula of error margin to python so I took help from AI to code for me. Anyone who know statistics and machine algorithms can comment.
import numpy as np

def calculate_confidence_interval(
    population_size, sample_size, sample_proportion, confidence_coefficient
):
    """
    This function calculates the confidence interval based on population size, sample size, sample proportion, and confidence coefficient.

    Parameters:
        population_size: Population size (N).
        sample_size: Sample size (n).
        sample_proportion: Proportion of individuals with a certain characteristic in the sample (p).
        confidence_coefficient: Confidence coefficient (z).

    Returns:
        Confidence interval (lower and upper bounds).
    """

    if sample_proportion < 0 or sample_proportion > 1:
        raise ValueError("Sample proportion must be between 0 and 1.")
    if confidence_coefficient <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Confidence coefficient must be greater than zero.")
    if sample_size <= 0 or population_size <= 0 or sample_size > population_size:
        raise ValueError(
            "Population and sample sizes must be greater than zero, and sample size should not exceed population size."
        )

    # Standard error
    standard_error = np.sqrt((sample_proportion * (1 - sample_proportion)) / sample_size)

    # Finite Population Correction (FPC) factor
    fpc = np.sqrt((population_size - sample_size) / (population_size - 1))

    # Margin of error
    error_margin = confidence_coefficient * standard_error * fpc

    # Confidence interval
    lower_bound = sample_proportion - error_margin
    upper_bound = sample_proportion + error_margin

    return lower_bound, upper_bound



# Given information
population_size = 19723003
sample_size = 197211
confidence_coefficient = 1.96
sample_proportion = 0.5  # Sample proportion can be assumed as 0.5 by default

lower_bound, upper_bound = calculate_confidence_interval(
    population_size, sample_size, sample_proportion, confidence_coefficient
)

print(f"Confidence interval: ({lower_bound:.4f}, {upper_bound:.4f})")

